# Как сделать скролл первого дива?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня шапка на всю высоту сайта, и мне нужно чтобы при скролее переходил вниз. НО дальше прокрутка была как обычно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/chayka/jQuery.Scroolly
Посмотрите в сторону этой библиотеки она поможет организовать скролл эффекты так как вы пожелаете.
Или тут https://github.com/Promo/scrollissimo как мне кажется данный вариант грамотнее реализован, но куда как сложнее в обращении.